# I want to add urdu language support in react.js web app

Tags: reactjs, urdu

I want to design my react js web app for both Urdu and English languages. Is there any help that can convert my react js web app in the Urdu language? I also want to write Urdu text in textfield. I will be thankful for the help.

Comment: What you're asking for is called "localization" and there are multiple approaches to it. I'd recommend trying https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ if you still need help, but this isn't a great question for stackoverflow.

Comment: I know I can make a multilingual web app by using the i18next library. Actually, I want to change the type of keyboard to Urdu by clicking on the checkbox. I want only two languages on my web ( English, URDU ). When I select Urdu my keyboard writes in the Urdu language, when I select English my keyboard writes in the English language.  Is it possible to react.js?  Please help me in this regard.

Comment: What you're asking for may be possible with the [lang attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) but I'm not certain. Are you trying to have a language selector on your website that changes the input language?

Comment: @john I want to change the keyboard type. If I select URDU my keyboard writes in URDU language and if I select English my keyboard writes the English language. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang this is also not helpful. I want all this in My React.js project. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: If you're talking about your physical keyboard, I don't believe a web browser is able to do this, that this is done at the operating system level. For virtual keyboards, you could do this by hand or with third-party libraries.

Comment: Yes I am talking about my physical keyborad.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle the problem with i18n library
https://react.i18next.com/
It's really simple and straighforward as you use json files to store all your translations